# How to reuse the old views in JSF

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-1.2, icefaces, icefaces-1.8

I have concurrent view limit exceeded problem in [icefaces](http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/21283.page#sthash.FaAnOA0a.dpbs). It supports not more than 50 views per one session. In the process of finding issue with the code, I have doubt regarding view reusability.

Consider the below cases.

Case 1:

Returning empty string would recreate a view though the user stays on the current page, as shown below.

```
 public String submit(){
          //...
          return "";
        }
```

Case 2:

But, below code would reuse the old view.

```
public String submit(){
      //...
      return null;
    }
```

Case 3:

I think, below code snippet would also do the same. Correct me here, if I am wrong.

```
public String submit() {
    // ...
    return "viewId?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

What is the difference between case 2 and case 3?

**UPDATE:**

I have tested an application with JSF 1.2, it allows all the 3 cases, as mentioned above.

[image]

In my bean I am using the following code

```
public String saveData() {
    //String returnString = "";//Case 1 : works - user stays on the same page
    //String returnString = null;//Case 2: works - user stays on the same page
    // Case 3:
    String viewId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId();
    System.out.println("view id = "+ viewId);
    String returnString = viewId+"?faces-redirect=true";
    System.out.println("return string = "+ returnString);
    return returnString;
}
```

I have deployed the above application in jetty.In the above example, every time the method `saveData()` is called, the user stays on the same page with his filled in data in input fields, I infer from this that, its reusing the old page or view(I am not clear with a view in JSF). This is happening in all the 3 cases, so not sure of the exact difference, How to experience this difference?  What is a view from JSF perspective?

Comment: Can you reconfirm that you're using JSF 1.2? Case 3 namely uses JSF 2.x specific syntax.

Comment: Well, then 3 won't work for you :)

Comment: @BalusC: The case 3 is also working fine. Now, I am not sure of the exact difference between case 2 and case 3.

Comment: Then you aren't using JSF 1.2.